# How to shift an in-text image vertically

Tags: graphics

I have the following shortcut command in the preamble

```
\def\craugh{\includegraphics[scale=0.033]{craughing.png}}
```

I have the following code in the document:

```
$$\int_0^{\alpha} \sqrt{a^2 \cos^2 \theta + b^2 \sin^2 \theta} \, \dd \theta = \mathcal{P A\, I\, N}\,\, \craugh{}$$
```

The following output is generated:

[image]

How can I vertically shift the emoji downwards in order to match the text height alignment? Assume I have appropriately changed the scale of the image so it has exactly the same height as the text.

Comment: may be `\raisebox` fulfill your requirement....

Comment: that answers my question, thanks very much!

Comment: I have entered this as in `answer` box..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `\raisebox{#1}{#2}`, where `#1` refers the point to move vertically and `#2` refers the text which needs to be move vertically. Example given below:

```
\[\int_0^{\alpha} \sqrt{a^2 \cos^2 \theta + b^2 \sin^2 \theta} \, \dd \theta = \mathcal{P A\, I\, N}\,\, \raisebox{10pt}{\craugh{}}\]
```

Comment: @Sebastiano Sorry, missed that, now corrected...